# How do I use a PARTUUID in fstab?

Tags: boot, partitioning

I needed to increase the size of my boot partition (I already removed old kernels with autoremove).
I increased the size of my drive (VM), and created a new partition.  I did all things wonderful to make the new partition /boot.  Blkid shows sda1 UUID=1234 PARTUUID=5678-01 and the new partition sda3 UUID=1234 PARTUUID=5678-03.
I tried adding PARTUUID="5678-03" /boot to my fstab but it didn't boot (it works with /dev/sda3 /boot).
Since partitions 1 and 3 are on the same disk (and the same UUID) how can I enter that in fstab?

Comment: I think it's `PARTUUID=5678-03  /boot` without the `"`'s what you have to use in `fstab`.

Answer (score 6):

As @mook765 mentions in comments, I think you can use PARTUUID, but just without quotes.

```
PARTUUID=5678-03 /boot [...]
```

Also, failing that, I think you can use the `/dev/disk/by-partuuid/*` symlinks that udev creates.

You may also want to use 'UUID', not 'PARTUUID'.  Here's an example of the boot section of my fstab (this is the default of Ubuntu):

```
# /boot was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=4e8a17a6-87ca-403b-9a1a-896d553e518c       /boot   ext3    defaults        0       2
UUID=7A56-4947  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults        0       1
```

To get the UUID of a block device:

```
sudo blkid /dev/sda1
/dev/sda1: LABEL="ubuntu-boot" UUID="4e8a17a6-87ca-403b-9a1a-896d553e518c" TYPE="ext3" PARTLABEL="ubuntu-boot" PARTUUID="57e3d2de-492b-4875-b110-76325e2401ec"
```

Just for example on another machine, you'll notice that each filesystem on the disk has a different UUID:

```
root@bierstadt:~# lsblk -o name,UUID /dev/sda
NAME                    UUID
sda                     
├─sda1                  8D99-B7B6
├─sda2                  147da7cf-c356-4ff9-a6fa-8fb555290b25
└─sda3                  1dd7ce7d-6de9-40e0-bd3f-5550ae40a588
  └─sda3_crypt          mAdSjw-3B31-Z7Im-WbCk-QmIP-b01M-5mFckC
    ├─ubuntu--vg-root   1b3d8c0f-2241-48c1-a272-39f8e683ccc9
    └─ubuntu--vg-swap_1 fd34789c-c65f-4253-a810-8183988e9760
```

Note the UUID comes with the **filesystem**.  So, if you have cloned the partition, the UUID will come with it.  You should probably change it if you want to mount it, or refer to it distinctly:

From [this blog](https://liquidat.wordpress.com/2013/03/13/uuids-and-linux-everything-you-ever-need-to-know/):

> Since it is not possible to mount two file systems with the same UUID,
>   extra care need to be taken when LVM snapshots (or cloned disks) are
>   used in an environment: mounting might fail due to duplicate UUIDs.
>   [...]
>   One way to deal with this is by the way to change the UUID during
>   creation or afterwards, another way is to mount with the nouuid
>   option.

To change:

```
# tune2fs -U new_uuid /dev/sdaX
```

## References

- https://liquidat.wordpress.com/2013/03/13/uuids-and-linux-everything-you-ever-need-to-know/
- https://wiki.debian.org/Part-UUID
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/fstab

Comment: Partition 1 and partition 3 are on the same drive and have the same UUID plus different PARTUUIDs.                                      /dev/sda1: UUID="e7b59339-f325-4631-a4eb-2ed5f6b12c45" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="db623058-01"
root@tjoe01:~# blkid /dev/sda3
/dev/sda3: UUID="e7b59339-f325-4631-a4eb-2ed5f6b12c45" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="db623058-03"

Comment: Check the updates on the question re: cloning, changing UUIDs, and the UUID coming with the Filesystem, not the partition, let me know if that helps.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, since what I did was create a new partition on the same drive and then clone the old partition to the new partition.  I will see if reformatting the old partition clears this up.  Thanks.

Comment: Note that in fstab the UUID must be written in all lowercase.

Comment: Avoid using the `/dev/...` syntax in `etc/fstab`. Per the man page for `mount`: "The recommended setup is to use tags (e.g. UUID=uuid) rather than /dev/disk/by-{label,uuid,partuuid,partlabel} udev symlinks in the /etc/fstab file. Tags are more readable, robust and portable." The reason tags are more robust is that the links in `/dev/` links may change across reboots. For example, `/dev/sdc` may become `/dev/sdb`. The tags will not change unless you force them to by using `tune2fs` or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

There were 2 partitions on this disk.  I was trying to increase the size of my /boot partition.  I added a new partition, umount'ed /boot and cloned it to the new partition.  This left me with identical UUID's on 2 partitions.  I did run tune2fs to create a random UUID for the old /boot partition.  Note, I did have to run grub-install /dev/sda to fix grub and allow reboot.  Alternately, I found I could fix grub and then add the old partition to the logical volume group to extend /, this also changed the UUID.  thanks for the ideas.